# Install SQL Server 2014 without SQL Server 2012 Native Client Tools

Tags: sql-server, installation, command-line

I am trying to install SQL 2014 through command line (via my installer setup to be precise).

Below is the INSTALL Command I use for a silent Installation of my SQL Server.

```
InstallCommand="/ACTION=Install /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /INDICATEPROGRESS /HIDECONSOLE /NPENABLED=1 /TCPENABLED=1 /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlServerInstance) /UpdateEnabled=0 /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=1  /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=P4nd4123 /SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
```

As can be seen, I am installing the named instance (PANDA) and FEATURE is `SQLEngine`

Now everything runs fine unless I have an existing SQL 2012/2014 installation.

Upon researching, I found that Any installation of SQL 2012/2014 also installs SQL 2012 Native Client Tools. And when that exists, the setup fails.

I can not ask users to uninstall it first. Instead, if there is a way where we can ask our install to skip installing SQL 2012 Native Client Tools so that the setup may continue.

I checked and it looks like there is a Feature command `"SNAC_SDK"`which installs the required tools. However I have not specified that in command.

Any reason why it could be failing and if I am doing something wrong.

Please let me know.

TIA

Ashutosh

Comment: Interesting question. Accordingly to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx#Feature `SQLEngine` must not install tools at all. If you have that in your environment, file a bug report and see what MS says.

Comment: BTW. In SQL2016 used following command and no tools were installed. Even `sqlcmd`: `d:\setup.exe /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /Q /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQLServer2016 /SAPWD=P4nd4123 /ACTION=Install /SECURITYMODE=SQL /UpdateEnabled=0 /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="MyWindowsAdminAccount"`

Comment: Did/can you try with SQL 2014 Express (which is what I tried).

Comment: Ok. Tried again and the command did not install SQL 2012 Native client when I do a fresh install. However, if there is SQL 2012 Native Client Installed, it fails. How can I get that to work

Comment: Uninstall the client?

Comment: My application's installer is also installing MS SQL. So during that process I do not have an option of manually uninstalling the client.

Comment: Wild guess, but if you have time ... Have you tried just `/FEATURES=SQL` instead of `/FEATURES=SQLEngine`?

Comment: No difference. Its still the same.

Comment: To add to it, here is what the log says.  `Process returned error: 0x84bc06aa`

Comment: Good idea. Check `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\1...0\Setup Bootstrap\Log\summary.txt` and check logs in underlying folders.